# Microsoft installer error in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects released for VS 2013. This allowed me to load my .vdproj file created on VS 2010. It all compiled fine. I ran the set up. It ran all the way and at the end displayed this 
[image]

After that the installation just reverses and goes back and installs nothing.

Comment: I see a file Config.InstallState in my setup project. The first line of this file looks like  Does this need modifications? <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a way to recreate the Config.InstallState file.

I found an answer in here 
 [Custom Action - Error 1001: Could not find file myApp.InstallState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063485/custom-action-error-1001-could-not-find-file-myapp-installstate)

The solution is to add the custom action to both the Install and the  Commit phases, although it does nothing >> during the install phase.

So this is what I did

1. Removed my old Config.Install from the Setup project.
2. Added the custom action to both the Install and Commit phase like the above solution.
3. Ran the Install - this created a new Config.InstallState file.
4. Copied this new Config.InstallState into my setup project and removed the custom action from the Install (only kept it for Commit phase)

Answer (score 0):

you can find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9298333/9984578):

> The problem is that the MSI infrastructure is looking for the installation state file which is usually created during the Install phase. If the custom action does not participate in the Install phase, no file is created.
>
> The solution is to add the custom action to both the Install and the Commit phases, although it does nothing during the install phase.